# Special Symbol in string as separator

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In application I pass data: id, listId and inputValue - as a string: 
`const string = '${id}|${listId}|${inputValue}'` 
 and then I need to create array with length 3 using split:

```
string.split("|")
```

Therefore, if user enter `'|'` inside the input - app crashes.
Is there any symbol that is impossible to write by user inside input and I can use as separator to get array with length 3?

Comment: What is the array output you want here?

Comment: No symbol is *impossible* to write. If you can write it, a user can write it. There are some that are *exceptionally unlikely* to be written and can generally be used for separators. But I think what you need to do here is step back and reexamine the problem: 1. Why is this a delimiter separated string instead of a different one? Why not JSON, in fact, which will handle all of this for you and is a standard and basic way to transfer data? 2. If JSON *for some reason* is not possible (again, why?) then why is "|" a valid symbol to enter? Are there any *invalid* ones? Can you make pipe invalid?

Comment: if data - id = 3, listId = 2 and inputValue = " Do | Die" 
I need [ 3 , 2, " Do | Die"

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem with `[id, listId, inputValue]`? You can `JSON.stringify()` it for transfer.

Comment: Sure, thank you very much. Pass it as an answer please.

Comment: Have a read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because what you asked was Y and *not* what you actually needed - the X.

Comment: @Umbert if a user can enter `|` because they are allowed to (no input validation?) then why wouldn't they be able to enter "%7C"? And in what way is *splitting a string* in order to create an array preferable over creating an array directly?

Comment: @VLAZ I don't know if that's the case here, but there are various ways in which strings may be preferred to arrays in some situations. For instance if they need to be used as keys in an object, if they need to be compared for equality and return true for the same inputs, or if they need to be serialized.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie "*For instance if they need to be used as keys in an object*" which isn't the case here. "*if they need to be compared for equality and return true for the same inputs*" also not the case here but arrays of primitives can be compared perfectly well with `arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((x, i) => arr2[i] === x)` "*or if they need to be serialized.*" JSON. There are occasional reasons to produce a string value but I'm talking *in the context of this question*. My comment started with explaining the situation *in the question*, so it wasn't a general query.